# Drools: Using globals defined at session creation for newly inserted rules

Tags: java, drools

Right, I'm running Drools in a ordering program I'm making. I was asked to make rules loadable during run of the program via JMX. I take these in as a String and add them to a StatefulKnowledgeSession's knowledgebase. So far all is well. I'm getting a simple test rule to load just fine and without incident.

However, when I start up the program I load a number of fixed global variables, for example a Logger. If I attempt to load a rule referencing these globals via JMX it says
`com/hipdm/messaging/Rule_Test_0.java (7:704) : logger cannot be resolved`
Is there a way to make this global visible to newly loaded rules? I have entered it into the same package as the rules loaded at startup.
The full rule:

```
package com.hipdm.messaging  

import com.hipdm.messaging.model.DummyOrderMessage  

rule "Test"  
   when $msg : DummyOrderMessage( processed == false ) from entry-point "Message stream"  
then  
   modify($msg) {process()};  
   logger.info("Order processed by rule engine");  
end
```

Any ideas what  may be wrong and how I can make my globals visible after the initial session creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the globals must be *'imported' into the rule file* to make them visible. There exists a special keyword in DRL: **global**. To do that add the following line after the *import* line in your rules.

```
global <full-class-name> <name-of-global-variable>
```

So if you are using a logger (assuming it is a log4j-logger) you would add:

```
global org.apache.log4j.Logger logger
```

Of course on the other end in the Java code the global must be *set to the working memory*, but I guess you managed to do that. In any case:

```
workingMemory.setGlobal("logger", someLogger);
```

Note that the 'logger' keyword must be exactly the same in the Java code and in your rules.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps out. Strange how the other startup rules can inherit from each other though. Ah well, the solution is indeed to import it via the global keyword.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the package thing lets you do some trickery so you don't need the import statements in each and every rule file. I'm no fan of this though, I like it better to have the imports stated clearly instead of introducing an extra layer of configuration with the packages file. (I guess thats what you meant, right?)